# statsmodels linear regression - patsy formula to include all predictors in model

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

Say I have a dataframe (let's call it `DF`) where `y` is the dependent variable and `x1, x2, x3` are my independent variables. In R I can fit a linear model using the following code, and the `.` will include all of my independent variables in the model:

```
# R code for fitting linear model
result = lm(y ~ ., data=DF)
```

I can't figure out how to do this with statsmodels using patsy formulas without explicitly adding all of my independent variables to the formula. Does patsy have an equivalent to R's `.`? I haven't had any luck finding it in the patsy documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No this doesn't exist in patsy yet, unfortunately. See this [issue](https://github.com/pydata/patsy/issues/10).

Answer (score 36):

I haven't found `.` equivalent in patsy documentation either. But what it lacks in conciseness, it can make-up for by giving strong string manipulation in Python. So, you can get formula involving all variable columns in `DF` using

```
all_columns = "+".join(DF.columns - ["y"])
```

This gives `x1+x2+x3` in your case. Finally, you can create a string formula using `y` and pass it to any fitting procedure

```
my_formula = "y~" + all_columns
result = lm(formula=my_formula, data=DF)
```

Comment: I'm currently using this approach - it is certainly nice to be able to do string manipulation in Python! I just wanted to make sure I wasn't overlooking something in patsy.

Comment: Yeah, and I guessed `.` is not available precisely because of string manipulation. Another example of dynamically constructing formula: pick all variables staring with `x` and not starting with `z`. Messy to do in R, but simple in Python. But again, if anyone knows patsy better, I'd love to find alternatives.

Comment: @SudeepJuvekar . I don't think so for the missing dot. R also have a strong and easy string manipulation(using paste,paste0) and provide a smart formula notation. So it is just a missing feature in pasty or not yet implemented.

Comment: The only reason it's not implemented in patsy is that neither I nor anyone else has found the time to do it yet :-)  There was one partial attempt here, from which the discussion is probably useful if someone else wants to have a go: https://github.com/pydata/patsy/pull/28

Comment: Thats all peachy, but what do you do when you get a `Maximum Recursion Depth Error` for your constructed formula? I have a sufficiently larger of dimensions than samples (p>>N). Also when I try `lm(formula="Y~.", data=df)` the error is that the dot isn't understood correctly. Any inspiration on those?

Comment: `DF.columns - ["y"]` gave me an error. The syntax which worked for me was `DF.columns.difference(["y"])`

Comment: @JeanPaul's reply worked for me instead of **DF.columns - ["y"]**

Answer (score 7):

As this is still not included in `patsy`, I wrote a small function that I call when I need to run `statsmodels` models with all columns (optionally with exceptions)

```py
def ols_formula(df, dependent_var, *excluded_cols):
    '''
    Generates the R style formula for statsmodels (patsy) given
    the dataframe, dependent variable and optional excluded columns
    as strings
    '''
    df_columns = list(df.columns.values)
    df_columns.remove(dependent_var)
    for col in excluded_cols:
        df_columns.remove(col)
    return dependent_var + ' ~ ' + ' + '.join(df_columns)
```

For example, for a dataframe called `df` with columns `y, x1, x2, x3`, running `ols_formula(df, 'y', 'x3')` returns `'y ~ x1 + x2'`

Comment: Could you please provide an example with several columns to exclude?